# Does the QR/Iwasawa decomposition have any geometric meaning for $2 \times 2$ complex matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, matrix-decomposition, mobius-transformation, symmetric-spaces

It's well known that $2 \times 2$ complex matrices act on the complex plane (with a point at infinity) by $\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}\cdot z = \frac{az + b}{cz + d}$.

Based on this, various matrix decompositions for $2 \times 2$ matrices gain simple meanings in planar geometry. Does the QR decomposition gain such a meaning? And if so, what is it?

Comment: Instead of talking about the "point at infiniity" please be more precise by using the complex projective line, which is the set of ratos $(z_1:z_2)$ where $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb C$ and $z_1$ and $z_2$ are not both 0. Then $$\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}. (z_1:z_2)=(az_1+bz_2:cz_1+dz_2)$$

Comment: Möbius transformations are stereographic projections of rotations of the Riemann sphere. Each rotation is a composite of a rotation around the vertical axis and a rotation around a line lying in the plane. The first one gives the Q part (rotation around the origin) and the second the R part (a transformation fixing two points on the plane and preserving their equidistant line). Honestly speaking I do not quite understand where did the loxodromic maps go. That is why I am commenting rather than answering.

Comment: @P.Lawrence It's always good to know where the "point at infinity" stuff comes from, but the "point at infinity" stuff is perfectly standard and precise enough in its own right.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Only Möbius transformations from $SU(2)$ yields rotations of the Riemann sphere via (the correct version of) stereographic projection. Applying elements of $SL(2,\Bbb C)$ outside $SU(2)$ yields transformations which are not rotations (e.g. a dilation on a sphere looks like it slides points from a "source" towards a "sink," corresponding to $0$ and $\infty$). If you use the sphere as the projectivized lightcone in one (time) dimension higher, then you can interpret all transformations as isometries WRT the Minkowski metric, though.

Answer (score 1):

In general the QR decomposition breaks a linear map down into an orthogonal (or unitary in the complex case) map and one that preserves a fixed flag. A flag here is a chain of subspaces $V_1 \leq V_2 \leq \cdots \leq V_n = \mathbb{C}^n$. In this example, a flag is exactly a line $L \leq \mathbb{C}^2$

We can think of the unitary matrices here as the ones which preserve a metric on the projective space and the upper triangular matrices as those which preserve a fixed line. So every transformation is the product of two transformations, one of which preserves the matric and one of which preserves a line.

Note immediately that this means $SU(2) \leq SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ acts transitively on the complex projective line.

More generally, we can see this fitting into the broader geometric picture that, for a real Lie group $G$ with a Borel subgroup $B$ (or any parabolic subgroup in fact), a maximal compact subgroup $K$ acts transitively on $G/B$. Alternatively, we could say this as the $G$-orbits of parabolic subgroups of $G$ are the same as the $K$-orbits.

Comment: What I meant was more like: The LDL decomposition gives the centre and radius of a circle on the plane; the spectral decomposition gives the centre and radius of a circle on the sphere; the PLU reduces Moebius transformations to translations, rotations, dilations and inversions.

Comment: I deleted a comment where I expressed slight annoyance. I appreciate you taking the take to write this answer, and I rescind my downvote. Thank you.

Comment: @wlad In those terms, the QR-decomp reduces Möbius transformations to (compositions of) unitary transformations, dilations and translations. Unitary is simply replacing the idea of rotations from the real version. Indeed, if we are viewing the complex projective line as the Riemann sphere, these are exactly the rotations of that sphere ($PSU(2) \cong SO(3)$).

Comment: I guess this wasn't quite what I was looking for. But at least there's enough facts here in one place.

Comment: @wlad Callum's comment (though not their answer) seems to me to be *exactly* what you were looking for. That said, I am curious to know more about the LDL and spectral interpretations you mention in your first comment. (I have played around with similar-sounding conclusions but don't remember them that specifically.)